# Parse.com android ParseRelation

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform, adapter, parse-android-sdk

I am developing SNS Application.
I tried to use ParseRelation. 
I created ParseUser and call the `getRelation()` function.
I put posts and call `currentUser.saveInBackground();`

I checked the saved relation posts in Parse.com Cloud. 
But when I call `currentUser.saveInBackground()`, my `ParseQueryAdapter` is called `loadObjects()`. I want to perform 'like' function like 'like'Button at FaceBook App.

And after performing all functions that are `saveInBackground()` and `loadObjects()`, My 'like' Buttons are not updated. 
What should I do? I tried various methods, but I can't solve this problem.

Comment: Your data is not changed before the save completes. If you enable local datastore and call saveeventually instead it should work I believe

Comment: I followed your comment. I checked saving the post I pick but My ParseQueryAdapter is not updated this button state. why?......

Comment: In my adapter(ParseQueryAdapter), I perform relation query at constructor, and I circle the objects of the relatrion query ( repeat method 'for') and saving to ArrayList<ParseObject> and I compare each object of posts with these ArrayList items. And my toggle button (List View Item, and LIKE BUTTON)
is set by this comparison.

Comment: I think you should make the state change inside `getItemView()`. Here you receive the parseobject for each list item (getItemView is called for each entry) and depending on the state of the parseobject, set your buttons etc.

Comment: I used getItemView(). This queryAdapter is used to load posted posts. Consequently, my question is a solution of two querys in one queryAdapter.
The first query is loading posts and the second query is getRelation() query. help me plz...